# MVVMLight ValueChanged event listener trigerred only for 3-4 times before stopping

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I have set up a binding in my Xamarin.Android activity where I am binding to a boolean property in my viewmodel using WhenSourceChanges().  I’ve also tried ValueChanged event and in both cases the event listener fire the first 3 or 4 times and then it just stops working. The value had definitely changed, I alternate between true and false, and yet it just stops working after a while. Do you know why this might be?

```
this.SetBinding(() => this.Vm.ShowErrorMessage)
.WhenSourceChanges(() =>
{
if (this.Vm.ShowErrorMessage)
{
    this.ErrorMsg.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
}
else
{
    this.ErrorMsg.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
}
});
```

I am using MvvmLightLibs v5.3.0, developing in VS2015 on A Win10 machine, and testing on an Android v4.2 Samsung Galaxy device.

Comment: Are you replacing the viewmodel somewhere? It sounds as if you are not using the viewmodel where the event is setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings are weak referenced, and will be garbage collected if you don’t save them. [Please watch my presentation here](http://galasoft.ch/presentations/presentationdetails.cshtml?name=2016006).

In your case what you need to do is something like that:

```
private List<Binding> _bindings = new List<Binding>();
```

and then

```
_bindings.Add(this.SetBinding(…)); // (the rest remains the same).
```

Comment: Thank you very much. :) Saving the bindings has resolved my issue.

Comment: @LBugnion i'm having the same issue has the OP and i'm storing the binding in a strong reference. It only happens after `GC.Collect()` is called. For now I just workaround it using the `ValueChanged`. Any thoughts on that?